# c# System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer

Tags: media-player

I don't have available the class System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer.

What I have to do to add System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer?

I have System.Windows.Media but i don't have available MediaPlayer method.

There is another way to add a clãss that read mp3 ou wmv sounds?

Answer (score 0):

You can find this class in PresentationCore.dll assembly.